# AutoML Translation　に関して

Tags: google-cloud, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

3つ質問があります。
①トレーニングに使用するデータをセットする際の3つの区分、トレーニング、検証、テストの役割（違い）および効果を教えていただきたいです。

②また「検証」、「テスト」に入力したデータはモデルの学習能力を向上させるのでしょうか？

③作成して1度トレーニングを実施したモデルを再度トレーニングさせることは可能でしょうか。
　可能であればその方法を教えてください。